# Powershell - "") was unexpected at this time

Tags: powershell

Estoy tratando de ejecutar lo siguiente en Powershell:

```
$args=("$env:ENV_URL, D:\WS\SOA_AR-CL-CO-EC-PE-UY\PACKAGE\$env:DOMAIN\$item, user='$env:USER', password='$env:PASSWORD', configplan='D:\WS\Orquestador_ESB\Repositorio\7.CFG_SOA\soaconfigplan_$env:ENV_NAME_$env:DOMAIN.xml', partition='$partition'")
$deploy=("sca_deployComposite($args)")
& $wlst $deploy
```

Cuándo le hago echo a $deploy recibo el valor esperado:
sca_deployComposite(una_URL, D:\WS\SOA_AR-CL-CO-EC-PE-UY\PACKAGE\SINC\algo.jar, user='un_usuario', password='un_password', configplan='D:\WS\Orquestador_ESB\Repositorio\7.CFG_SOA\soaconfigplan_SINC.xml', partition=una_particion)

Sin embargo, al ejecutar & $wlst $deploy me devuelve el error
"") was unexpected at this time.

Estoy bastante seguro que está relacionado con las comillas pero ya probé muchísimas variantes y no puedo encontrar el error.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Una cosa, "args" es un nombre reservado.  Hay que usar otro, como argsz o algo.

Comment: gracias! pero pensás que ese es el problema ?

Comment: No sé.  No dijo lo que es $wslt o porque necesita el &.

Comment: perdón, explico un poco más:
el & es porque se ejecuta desde Jenkins y debería encadenar los comandos
el $wlst es una invocación a un script que abre la consola de WebLogic dónde se debería ejecutar $deploy --> el valor es:    $wlst='C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd'

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que los parenteses que rodean $args deben ser omitidos.  Si Sca_delpoyComposite es una funcion,  Debe llamarse sin parentesis.

Tambien es posible que $args deberia ser @args.

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo voy a probar